# Is sharing your ports with other players legal?

Tags: catan

Catan 5th edition.

Assuming I have a settlement on say a 2:1 sheep port.

Can I let others use my port in exchange for a small/no commission? If yes, are there rules governing when they might be allowed to do this? Are they restricted to use it only on my turn out can they also use my port on their own turn as well?

Is it mandatory for me to pocket a commission ( say 3 sheep for 1 ore, where I pocket the extra sheep)? Or may I let others use it on goodwill?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ports/harbors enhance the maritime trade. This is a trade between one player and the bank. You can only use maritime trade during your turn. So it is not possible to offer port services to other players.

From [the rules](https://www.catan.com/service/game-rules):

> You can also trade without the other players! During your turn, you can always trade at 4:1 by putting 4 identical resoirce cards back in their stack and taing a 1 resource card of your choice for it. If you have a settlement or city on a harbor, you can trade with the bank more favorably: at either 3:1 ratio or, in certain harbors, at 2:1 (trading resource type shown).

However, you can trade the turn of the player owning the port in several steps. Using your example (Player A wants to trade 3 sheep for an ore with player B who does not have an ore yet.

- On his turn, Player B trades a wood (or an other non sheep/ore) for two sheep with player A.
- Player B uses his port to trade two sheep for one ore.
- Player B trades the ore for the sheep and the wood.

The effect is the same. It is only possible on the turn of the player owning the port

Comment: This leaves the question of Player A trades 2 sheep to Player B for nothing, Player B trades the sheep for a ore in the port, Player B trades the ore to player A for nothing (or for his commision).  Is this legal, and can a binding agreement be made prior to the first trade?

Comment: @Taemyr you can do the double trade. You can't have a binding agreement.

Comment: @taemyr Note the restriction against trading for nothing. So you'd have to get more creative in your accounting to ensure that each trade involved an actual exchange of resources.